# Javascript code to open a url on click in the same window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im' stuck in a probably easy problem. Sorry I'm a beginner !

I have this

```
<div class="icon-1"></div>
<div class="icon-2"></div>

<script>  
 $(function() { 
  onclick('icon-1').openurl('http://acdefg.com');
  onclick('icon-2').openurl('http://ghijkl.com');
 }
</script>
```

...I mean, that if I click on "icon-1", then I go to URL "...."
If i click on "icon-2" then I go to URL "..."

etc.

Could you please help me ?

Comment: 1. You need to fix your formatting so the HTML shows up (put 4 spaces in front of code, or just use the {} button)
2. why Javascript and not just making them clickable images with HTML?

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast ! :)
I have to do it in Javascript because I need to include it in wordpress and I can't change the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could define something like:

```
document.getElementByClassName("icon-1").onclick=function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://abcdef.com';
};
```

You could also pull in an elements attribute (for examle, data-href) to full in the variable (instead of setting it specifically in JS, then you would only need 1 JS function for all occurrences).

However, can I ask - why don't you just use HTML a tags with href values?

Comment: I can't modify the HTML because it's in Wordpress.
I've tried your code but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Hi,

sorry, try this ammendment;

`document.getElementsByClassName("icon-1")[0].onclick = function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://abcdef.com';
};`

Comment: Nope sorry it still doesn't work. I don't understand !

Comment: Did you copy what I wrote in my last comment exactly?

As I can confirm it works - which implies theres possibly other code on the page breaking your JS (if you're in chrome and you right click -> Inspect element, the console at the bottom should tell you of any JS errors while on the page)

Comment: Yes, I copied it exactly. I've added the code directly in the box where I want to activate the elements. There's probably a conflict. I'm checking with the console. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery (which is bundled with WordPress): https://jsfiddle.net/wu24bnbc/2/

```
<div class="icon-1">Icon 1</div>
<div class="icon-2">Icon 2</div>

<script>
    jQuery(function() { 
        jQuery('.icon-1').click(function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://acdefg.com';
        });

      jQuery('.icon-2').click(function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://ghijkl.com';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Edit: I think you need to use jQuery instead of the $ shorthand with WP.

Comment: Nope sorry it still doesn't work. I don't understand !

Comment: @Elsupero where are you adding this code? Can you give us more information? Try using console.log to trace the problem.

Comment: Hello ! I've added the code directly in the box where I want to activate the elements. There's probably a conflict. I'm checking with the console. Thanks !